# Изменение полей со списком (Swing) (Java)

Tags: java, swing

**Суть :**

Не получается присвоить "кнопке-список" список своих элементов

Есть

```
ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList();
```

также есть строка в классе с GUI

```
jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[]{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"}));
```

работаю в NetBeans,не удается с присвоить кнопке со списком свой список.
На зарубежных интернетах нашел такое:

```
jComboBox1.removeAllItems();

    for (int i = 0; i <  users.size(); i++) {
     jComboBox1.addItem(users.get(i));
    }
```

**ПРОБЛЕМЫ ПРИКРЕПЛЕННЫХ НИЖЕ ОТВЕТОВ :**

```
     jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[]{"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"}));
        jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
        String [] items = new String [10];
        for (int i = 0; i < new ListFriend().nameSurname.size(); i++) {
        items[i] = new ListFriend().nameSurname.get(i);

      }

      jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(items));
```

в итоге элементы-то я получил,но они не отображаются. В чём причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   jComboBox1.setModel(myModel);
    myModel.add("Hello");
    myModel.add("Hel23lo");
    myModel.add("Hell3wso");
    for (int i = 0; i < new ListFriend().nameSurname.size(); i++) {
    String r = new ListFriend().nameSurname.get(i);
    myModel.add(r);
    }
```

если попробовать так то тоже не работает,он не закидывает элементы массива в список,кроме тех,которые были добавлены через просто myModel.add
он не дает возможность добавлять через цикл.

если написать даже так :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String r = "hello world";
    new MyModel().add(r);
    }
```

он всё равно не будет добавлять их.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54789/discussion-on-question-by-mazimrat-----swing-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько способов динамически добавлять в `JComboBox` элементы. Самым правильным способом будет создать объект реализующий интерфейс `ComboBoxModel` и передать его в `JComboBox`.

После этого добавление и удаление элементов нужно делать в этом объекте, а `JComboBox` будет отображать изменения автоматически.

Вот простой вариант реализации для хранения строк (String).

```
public class MyModel extends AbstractListModel<String> implements ComboBoxModel<String> {
    private List<String> list;
    private String selected;

    public MyModel() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void remove(String item) {
        list.remove(item);
        fireContentsChanged(this, 0, list.size());
    }

    public void add(String item) {
        list.add(item);
        fireContentsChanged(this, 0, list.size());
    }

    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getElementAt(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(Object item) {
        selected = (String) item;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSelectedItem() {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

Использовать это так. Создание:

```
MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
JComboBox<String> = new JComboBox<>(myModel);
```

Добавление/удаление элементов:

```
myModel.add("hello");
myModel.add("world");
myModel.remove("hello");
// добавить элементы в цикле
// поскольку мы храним строки, то при добавлении элемента его необходимо привести типу String
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    myModel.add("" + i); // сложение с пустой строкой один из способов приведения к String
}
```

Если у вас есть готовый список строк, то его можно добавить вот так

```
List<String> r = new ArrayList<>();

// предположим, что тут r заполняется значениями

// добавляем значения в ComboBox
for(String i: r) {
    myModel.add(i);
}
```

Вот тут можно найти рабочий пример приложения - [SimpleMVC](https://github.com/Vaysman/SimpleMVC), правда там я использую `JList`, но принцип такой же.

Comment: я ответ сейчас прикреплю снизу посмотрите как исправить )

Comment: прикрепил ответ,посмотрите

Comment: попробовал с вашим кодом и со своим,программа вроде как работает,а вот в поле-список он их не видит

Comment: сосбственно проблема в том,что по вашей команде если вводить myModel.add("Hello); он добавляет значения в список,а вот если вытаскивать их из myModel.add(ListArray().get(i)); то оно не работает

Comment: jComboBox1.setModel(myModel);
        myModel.add("Hello");
        myModel.add("Hel23lo");
        myModel.add("Hell3wso");
        for (int i = 0; i < new ListFriend().nameSurname.size(); i++) {
        String r = new ListFriend().nameSurname.get(i);
        myModel.add(r);
        }  

если попробовать так то тоже не работает,он не закидывает элементы массива в список.

Comment: в общем в самом вопросе добавил что не работает используя ваш код

Comment: @mazimrat дополнил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если про `javax.swing.JComboBox<E>` речь, то он в конструкторе массив принимает
`JComboBox(E[] items)`
 [Creates a JComboBox that contains the elements in the specified array.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html)

```
String[] items = {
"item1",
"item2",
"item3"
};
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(items);
```

Comment: суть в том,что как мне динамический массив запихнуть в массив строк...